# How to get sum of instance for grafana query

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In my grafana I am tracking the running instance of node exporter and process exporter. In that i have used the query

```
namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary"}
```

For this query I am getting multiple process running instance for node exporter and process exporter. For example for the above query i am getting the result like,

```
namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary",groupname="processexporter",job="processexporter"} 45678
namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary",groupname="processexporter",job="processexporter"} 98767
namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary",groupname="nodeexporter",job="nodeexporter"} 64835
namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary",groupname="nodeexporter",job="nodeexporter"} 36217
```

I want to alter the query to display the sum of total running instace like,

```
namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary",groupname="processexporter",job="processexporter"} 144445
namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary",groupname="nodeexporter",job="nodeexporter"} 101052
```

Kindly assist me on how to achieve the sum value of running instance

Answer (score 11):

I achieved by running the query

```
sum by (groupname) (namedprocess_namegroup_context_switches_total{ctxswitchtype="voluntary"})
```

We can use any of tags inside the sum by (use any tag) such as job, groupname, ctxswitchtype to filter

Answer (score 0):

You can pass instance name as label to the counter and then you get sum of each instance by running:

```
sum by (instance) (metric_name_total)
```

For more information check link below:

https://community.grafana.com/t/sum-values-grup-by-instance/62414